# WF OutputParameters - How do I stop a dependency property from becoming one?

Tags: workflow-foundation

In WWF 3.5, how do I stop a property of the workflow from becoming part of the OutputParameters after the workflow's completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All public readable properties are returned as WorkflowCompletedEventArgs OutputParameters. I typically make properties internal to prevent this from happening. Using fields instead of properties is another option.